# Could someone identiy this SMD connector?

Tags: connector, identification

does someone know what the part number etc of this connector is? It is used to connect two boards. There are 5 pins on one side and 6 pins on the other. The smallest markings on the tape measure are in mm.

[image: side view]
[image: top view]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This connector is a Mezzanine connector from Amphenol ICC of the Conan/MezzSelect line.

Now, depending on your mating height it can be one of two or three models, but visually it looks like the 6mm version: [91911-31411LF Digikey.com](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/amphenol-icc-fci/91911-31411LF/609-3431-1-ND/1878877)

Be careful to measure your mating height beforehand to [order the correct one](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/rectangular-connectors-arrays-edge-type-mezzanine-board-to-board/308?k=&pkeyword=&sv=0&pv28=353524&sf=1&FV=88%7C74826%2C-8%7C308%2C-5%7C8532%2C-1%7C609&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=25). 
[image]

You can refer to the [Amphenol Conan 92053 datasheets.](https://cdn.amphenol-icc.com/media/wysiwyg/files/drawing/91900.pdf?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=5fb435af00b8a723d2e7f5cbf2e88b709bd0e5e0-1582331543-0-ATfBuZ7X6rE_OvHIBtZOR_rZkeVBIYpE4cBOX5lyHudVUYo_wge_RYSE3O6mLa_hSucyeOubeHug4Eaailv-wVfnWcRdrt61pEgT56uurGDl_5VweFbBxVU7mZThNg_fnTrbx-oP5OrPv4t3lEsCpheNL9rnRyitOLzKEMxkSfHpQ-4v-zXjr_UTJP0z7-O2S_b6iimK5JXXNvNoKYLXj5bLtNZu0I_SR0f6bBBd55z4D_xBaI7MgSvuYx7W-2Dgd2KSymd4fhrnvTTJmDBh61qcMZEgOuQD9c23pAhvbSnF1k3dsnXQI1TfkHdZOPlwriLdRAixIIWrRoeTgD1kDK-DqgN0UUMxq82uYEQZ6LfaVt7OCVs1eh2Ud4J9x6RBlw)